# Prevent "&#09;" from becoming "&amp;#09;"

Tags: xml, excel, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to export XML from Excel. Some of my cells have tabs in them if the form of `&#09;` but when they export to XML they become `&amp;#09;`.
I am able to fix this in SublimeText with a simple find/replace but it would be nice to just have it come out right. Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

`&#09;` is how a tab is written in XML. If it would be a real tab, it would be whitespace and ignored.

So the extract is correct, and your 'correction' would break it.

Comment: Im sorry im not sure what happened to my question. the stuff in quotes isn't right. what is happening is that where "&#09;" occurs in the spreadsheet "&amp;#09;" is generated on export. Sorry for the mixup. not sure why that happened.

Comment: I see. My display adds another level of confusion... I understand your problem now.